Variable is only applied to prefab sometimes when instantiated in Unity 2d
I am working on a factory build game. When placing down specific buildings such as the market that sells ores and the chest that stores the ores, I need to access the GameManager GameObject in my Scene. Since the buildings are prefabs, I set the variable on placement. Sometimes, seemingly randomly, the variable will not be set. The BuildManager code is below.
GameObject Tower = Instantiate(towerToBuild, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Quaternion.identity);

if (towerToBuild == market)
{
    MarketScript marketScript = towerToBuild.GetComponent<MarketScript>();
    marketScript.gameManager_ = gameManager;
}

if (towerToBuild == chest) 
{
    StorageScript storageScript = towerToBuild.GetComponent<StorageScript>();
    storageScript.gameManager_ = gameManager;
}

The variable that is not being set is the gameManager_ variable in my storage and market scripts.
The code works about 80-90% of the time. Also when placing the builds I am doing nothing different between times when the code works and when it does not. It seems to me to be completely random.

looks like an interface would save you hassle and code, but, have you added debug statements, checked that towerbuild is either market or chest etc?

Now that I added the debugs I'm not getting the bug anymore, I think it might have been a lag problem? I will leave another comment if it starts up again. Also, what do you mean by an interface?

Look up c# interfaces.. saves a lot of repeated code amongst shared things, such as here, lets say you have IManager, they all agree to have a property of gameManager, all you'd need is GetComponent()?.gameManager_=gameManager.

You're modifying the tower prefab, not the newly created object. This means that the gameManager_ variable will not be set for the first object created of a given type, but it will be set for every copy created after the first.
MarketScript marketScript = towerToBuild.GetComponent<MarketScript>();
marketScript.gameManager_ = gameManager;

Change towerToBuild.GetComponent(...) to Tower.GetComponent(...), since Tower is the variable containing the newly created gameObject:
MarketScript marketScript = Tower.GetComponent<MarketScript>();
marketScript.gameManager_ = gameManager;

